# How to get page coordinates inside pdf document onclick

Tags: pdf, coordinates

Is there any API in js or .net or any other free tool through which page coordinates can be obtained in a pdf? Basically, I have a pdf file which contains images so I have read the coordinates on click inside the pdf document.

*coordinates here refer to .pdf page coordinates and not pixel coordinates, however I used itext library but couldn't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read the coordinates of an image when it's clicked on in the PDF, you're going to need to use a PDF viewer that is capable of running scripts. Unfortunately, there are only a few of those and they all implement only a  portion of the Acrobat JavaScript API but the Acrobat JavaScript API can't tell you anything about images or their location so it's doubtful that any of the others would. However, you could create a plug-in to Reader and/or Acrobat and add that functionality but then all of your users would need to install both Acrobat/Reader and your plug-in.

Assuming I understood the user experience you are looking for, I don't think it's possible without a customized viewer.